# PHP array twice and value at the end

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I am to get an array to append to string and dismiss the value if the value is "". Somehow, the resulting array is this:
`Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test2 [2] => t3 [3] => t4 [4] => t5 [5] => t6 ) test1,test2,t3,t4,t5,t6`

The php code:

```
<?php
include ('connServer.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
//$query = 

$updatedBy = $_POST['username'];
$shift = $_POST['shift'];
$date = $_POST['currDate'];
$machine = $_POST['machine'];
$timeDown = $_POST['timeDown'];
$timeUp = $_POST['timeUp'];
$downtimeType = $_POST['dtType'];
$tsDowntime = $_POST['troubleDT'];
$proDowntime = $_POST['proDowntime'];

function is_notnull($var) {return !is_null($var);}

switch ($downtimeType)
{
    case "Unscheduled":
    {
        $process = '-';
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $actiontaken = $_POST['details'];
        $remark = '-';
        $sparepartstaken = $_POST['sparepartsTaken'];
    }break;

    case "PM":
    {
        $rebuiltParts = array();
        for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++)
        {
            $rebuiltParts[] = $_POST['rebuildParts'.$i];
            $rebuiltPartsfiltered = array_filter($rebuiltParts, "is_notnull");
        }
        print_r(array_filter($rebuiltParts, "is_notnull"));
        $process = '-';
        $description = "Rebuilt Parts:" .implode(',',$rebuiltPartsfiltered). "";
        $actiontaken = $_POST['actTaken'];
        $remark = '-';
        $sparepartstaken = $_POST['sparepartsTaken'];
    }break;

    case "Conversion":
    {
        $process = '-';
        $description = '' .$_POST['description']. '';
        $actiontaken = $_POST['actTaken'];
        $remark = '-';
        $sparepartstaken = $_POST['sparepartsTaken'];
    }break;

    case "Process_Issue":
    {
        $process = '-';
        $description = '' .$_POST['description']. '';
        $actiontaken = $_POST['actTaken'];
        $remark = '-';
        $sparepartstaken = $_POST['sparepartsTaken'];
    }break;

    case "Others":
    {
    }break;

    case "Bi-Weekly":
    {}break;

    default:
    {} break;
}
print_r(implode(',',$rebuiltPartsfiltered));
/*  
$process
$description
$actiontaken
$remark
$sparepartstaken
*/
}
?>
```

searched and tried other things, but it only got worse. But I don't really know how to exactly express this in Google Search. Am I doing it wrong (I believe it could be the `for` loop) or something else? Or there are better ways to do this?

Comment: For starters, move the `array_filter` line of code. It should be after your `for` loop, not inside it.

Comment: no need for special flavoring and some stuff, just use `array_filter` outright (no custom method whatsoever), it already filters falsy stuff inside it, you have to be careful about `0` if you want that intact though

Comment: @jszobody Thats just for posting here sir. In my code its outside.

Comment: @HardysonArthy you're making it hard on yourself then by not showing us your _actual_ code. Update your question with the code you're really running.

Comment: @jszobody updated with the whole code. the html is just input type text. still progressing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your output:

> Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test2 [2] => t3 [3] => t4 [4] => t5 [5] => t6 ) test1,test2,t3,t4,t5,t6

Makes perfect sense. You first have this code...

```
print_r(array_filter($rebuiltParts, "is_notnull"));
```

... which is printing out an array. That is generating this output:

> Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test2 [2] => t3 [3] => t4 [4] => t5 [5] => t6 )

Then at the very end you have this code...

```
print_r(implode(',',$rebuiltPartsfiltered));
```

Which is printing out array values as a comma-separated string. Which is generating this output:

> test1,test2,t3,t4,t5,t6

Comment: Damn.. made myself a fool. Thanks sir. Have yourself a good day.